# What's that weird feeling I sometimes get in my stomach?

Tags: psychology, emotions

I can't really explain it but it's almost like my stomach feels tickly,but in a bad way,and kinda empty.I usually get it when I'm in public places(i.e. in class or out with friends) and it's like my skin is exposed and I feel really vulnerable like I want to be home wrapped in a blanket or something.Yeah I can't really describe it any better.Do you guys get this ever and do you know how to stop cause I really don't like it when it happens. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not English Language and Usage.

Comment: the psychology or heath forums may be helpful here

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't asking about the English Language.

Answer (score 4):

The most probable expression describing what you say is "**having butterflies in one's stomach**", though that can be either negative (when performing in public for example) or positive (when one is in love - although even there it could arguably be an unpleasant symptom of being in love).

It sounds like you may have **social anxiety**. This is not the appropriate forum to discuss how you should deal with that, but if you were looking for words to use to ask people for help, well that would be one.

You would probably learn more on https://health.stackexchange.com or https://psychology.stackexchange.com, but if you ask a question there you should try and make it more specific, and more about increasing your understanding of the condition and less seeking personal advice; StackExchange is not an advice forum.